# How to show natbib reference as "first author et al"?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a problem with a citation call-out generated with the natbib package

I get this  [Y. Kuwata, M. T. Wolf, D. Zarzhitsky and T. L. Huntsberger, 2013]

I would like [Kuwata et al., 2013]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[square, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}
I get this  \citep{VO}  
[Y. Kuwata, M. T. Wolf, D. Zarzhitsky and T. L. Huntsberger, 2013]

I would like [Kuwata et al., 2013]
%%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{Sample} 

\end{document}
```

My Sample.bib

```
@article{VO,
    author =       "{Y. {Kuwata}, M. T. {Wolf}, D. {Zarzhitsky} and T. L. {Huntsberger}}",    
    title =        "{\emph{Safe Maritime Autonomous Navigation With COLREGS, Using Velocity Obstacles}}",
    journal =      {IEEE Journal of Oceanic Enginerring} ,
    volume =       {39},
    number =       {1},
    pages =        {110 - 119},
    year =         {2013},
    DOI =          {10.1109/JOE.2013.2254214}
}
```

I have looked around, and tried different things that I found (in here) as changing `plainnat`  to `chicago`

Am I all wrong or is it not possible to do this with natbib?

I want to keep the bibliography with all names, year, title, journal, volume, number, pages. 
but add DOI at the last as a hyperlink

Comment: `author = {Y. Kuwata and M. T. Wolf and D. Zarzhitsky and T. L. Huntsberger},`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to how you input the data, BibTeX sees just one author of your paper, because there's an additional pair of braces that shouldn't be there. Also, the different authors should be separated by the keyword “and”.

Here's the proper code:

```
author = "Y. Kuwata and M. T. Wolf and D. Zarzhitsky and T. L. Huntsberger",
```

Comment: I don't know how I have been ably to completely misunderstand  that part. 
But what is the difference between using "x" and {x}   Nothing right?

Comment: @Mikkel Not really, this may affect collation. But the main thing is removing the additional braces around the whole list and using `and` between names.

Comment: @Mikkel - BibTeX is not TeX. BibTeX employs the concept of brace groups, and it treats stuff differently depending on whether the stuff is in brace group 0, 1, 2, etc. Thus, as far as BibTeX is concerned, `{Kuwata}` and `Kuwata` are *not* the same.

Comment: @Mico I think @Mikkel was asking about the difference between `{x}` and `"x"` (note the quotes) on the outermost level, and that, for bibtex, is the same (only that quotes cannot be nested).

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for pointing out this nuance. I should have written that for BibTeX, `"x"` and `"{x}"` are not the same, and thus that `"... {Kuwata} ..."` and `"... Kuwata ..."` are also not the same.